# PHP Intervention-image, avoid none image and exceptions to crash execution

Tags: php, image, exception, intervention

I am building a filemanager. When I fetch all files, I make sure I have a thumbnail for the filemanager instead of loading big images into the view.

**Problem**

If the file is not an image, the intervention library will throw an exception. Of course, this is how it should be.I have a simple file extension check which is not a secure way of finding out it is an image or not.
I will also get an exception if the source file does not exists. And maybe when other problems appear.

```
Image::make($source)
->resize(300, 300,  function ($constraint) {
    $constraint->aspectRatio();
    $constraint->upsize();
})
->save(Storage::disk()->path($target), $quality);
```

**What I want to solve; The question**

I don't want the exceptions to kill the whole process. This means that the filemanager crashes just because of wrong filetypes or any other problem.

Can I ignore the exception and just don't create a thumbnail and continue the PHP execution?

Comment: Well, if you read some most basic introduction into how exceptions are used you will find how to "catch" an exception. So: read the manual. Thanks.

Comment: I tried wrap the code inside a try-catch and do nothing in the catch, without success.

Comment: I found out that I need to type exactly which exception instance I expecting:
`catch (\Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException $e)`
Can I catch all type of exceptions?

Comment: Sure you can. All exceptions type (classes) are (if implemented correctly) derived from a common base class called "Exception". If you catch exceptions of a parent class all exceptions that are instantiations of that parents child class are caught too. (Sorry for the late response, had a flight to catch...)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Okey sounds great but I don't get that to work.

`Intervention\Image\Exception\NotReadableException`
This exception is thrown. It extends: `Intervention\Image\Exception\ImageException`

So I thought I could do this:
`                } catch (Intervention\Image\Exception\ImageException $e) {
                    return '';
                }`

But it does not catch it.

Comment: Kidding! It works great, thanks :) 
I forgot to add a \ before (different namespaces)

Comment: Glad to hear you are a step further. Have fun!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct answer in comments, by @arkascha

> All exceptions type (classes) are (if implemented correctly) derived from a common base class called "Exception". If you catch exceptions of a parent class all exceptions that are instantiations of that parents child class are caught too. (Sorry for the late response, had a flight to catch...)
>
> try { ... } catch (\Exception $e) { }

*Works because all exceptions extends to it*